# Keyboard acting funny

Tags: keyboard

After searching, I couldn't find any similar issue to mine, and solutions for other problems didn't help.

I have an Acer laptop at work, and an USB keyboard plugged. The issue is (in both, the laptop keyboard, and the USB keyboard) that, from time to time, random keys won't work, but others will. For instance, characters' keys will stop working, but the letter n,m and all the punctuation symbols will work. Also, it also happens that sometimes, the keys that work, will take forever to actually type, or delete.

I don't recall doing anything, or installing anything new, other than just updating a couple of days ago.

Comment: Since it is a USB keyboard, first thing that you should do is it plug in to another system and check if the fault is with your keyboard. At times, the keys may be shorted or loosely connected because of corrosion.

Comment: Forgot to mention, when the error happens, it also happens on the laptop keyboard, not only on the USB one.

Comment: Try to boot into a Live CD/USB, choose try Ubuntu and check if the problem persists. If yes, then it is definitely hardware problem.